# Turning JavaScript example into Typescript and failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Trying to learn both TypeScript and JavaScript. Having trouble with translating this AuthContext code from [this tutorial](https://blog.devgenius.io/django-rest-framework-react-authentication-workflow-2022-part-2-d299b7fef875) into typescript.

This is the original code

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export default AuthContext;

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState(() =>
    localStorage.getItem("authTokens")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authTokens"))
      : null
  );
  const [user, setUser] = useState(() =>
    localStorage.getItem("authTokens")
      ? jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem("authTokens"))
      : null
  );
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const history = useHistory();

  const loginUser = async (username, password) => {
    const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        password
      })
    });
    const data = await response.json();

    if (response.status === 200) {
      setAuthTokens(data);
      setUser(jwt_decode(data.access));
      localStorage.setItem("authTokens", JSON.stringify(data));
      history.push("/");
    } else {
      alert("Something went wrong!");
    }
  };
  
  const registerUser = async (username, password, password2) => {
    const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        password,
        password2
      })
    });
    if (response.status === 201) {
      history.push("/login");
    } else {
      alert("Something went wrong!");
    }
  };

  const logoutUser = () => {
    setAuthTokens(null);
    setUser(null);
    localStorage.removeItem("authTokens");
    history.push("/");
  };

  const contextData = {
    user,
    setUser,
    authTokens,
    setAuthTokens,
    registerUser,
    loginUser,
    logoutUser
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (authTokens) {
      setUser(jwt_decode(authTokens.access));
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }, [authTokens, loading]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData}>
      {loading ? null : children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

This is my attempt

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthContext = createContext(null);

export function AuthProvider(children:any) {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(() => 
    localStorage.getItem("authTokens")
    ? jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem("authTokens") || '{}') : null
    );

    const [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState(() =>
    localStorage.getItem("authTokens")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authTokens") || '{}')
    : null
    );

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    async function loginUser(username: string, password: string) {
        const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,
                password
            })
        });
        const data = await response.json();

        if (response.status === 200) {
            setAuthTokens(data);
            setUser(jwt_decode(data.access));
            localStorage.setItem("authTokens", JSON.stringify(data));
            redirect("/");
        } else {
            alert("Something went wrong on login!");
        }
    }

    async function registerUser(username: string, password: string, password2: string) {
        const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,
                password,
                password2
            })
        });
        if (response.status === 201) {
            redirect("/login");
        } else {
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
    }

    async function logoutUser() {
        setAuthTokens(null);
        setUser(null);
        localStorage.removeItem("authTokens");
        redirect("/");
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (authTokens) {
            setUser(jwt_decode(authTokens.access));
        }
        setLoading(false);
    }, [authTokens, loading]);

    const contextData: contextData = {
        user: user,
        setUser: setUser,
        authTokens: authTokens,
        setAuthTokens: setAuthTokens,
        registerUser: registerUser,
        loginUser: loginUser,
        logoutUser: 
      };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={}>
            {loading ? null: children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

}
export default AuthContext;
```

I'm stuck with the

```
  const contextData = {
    user,
    setUser,
    authTokens,
    setAuthTokens,
    registerUser,
    loginUser,
    logoutUser
  };
```

and value in

```
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData}>
      {loading ? null : children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

I think that the constant should actually be an interface definition with a const that pulls all of that together and takes it's place? I've failed to get it to work though.

I'm also not sure what to do about value, since it always seems to yell at me about typing it even though it's defined as  in the TypeScript types for createContext, so I though that meant it's essentially any?

I could just be vastly misunderstanding everything and stuck fooling myself that I'm kind of understanding any of this. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that you need a type definition for the contextData. Something like this:

```
interface AuthToken {
    name: string
    exp: number
}

interface ContextData  {
    user: string | null
    setUser: (value: string) => void,
    authTokens: AuthToken | null, // AuthToken[] | null if multiple
    setAuthTokens: (authToken: string) => void,
    registerUser: (username: string, password: string, password2: string) => void,
    loginUser: (username: string, password: string) => void,
    logoutUser: () => void
  };
```

Comment: Any recommendation on the best way to figure that out?

Comment: You had it right in const contextData: ContextData = {...}. What errors are you getting?

Comment: user in const contextData gives
```Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.ts(2322)
```

value in the reutrn above gives

```Type 'contextData' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)```